# WCF debugging not able to understand

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to debug a custom self hosted WCF service on production server (no visual studio, nothing..) I modified WCF service web.config and added tracelistener as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx), but all I am getting entries like this, which makes no sense

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"> 
<System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"> 
<EventID>524324</EventID> 
<Type>3</Type> 
<SubType Name="Verbose">0</SubType> 
<Level>16</Level> 
<TimeCreated SystemTime="2014-06-27T13:55:07.6585544Z"/> 
<Source Name="System.ServiceModel"/> 
<Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}"/> 
<Execution ProcessName="w3wp" ProcessID="4564" ThreadID="6"/> 
<Channel/> 
<Computer>SERVER-NAME</Computer> 
</System> 
<ApplicationData> 
<TraceData> 
<DataItem> 
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Verbose"> 
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/System.ServiceModel.GetConfigurationSection.aspx</TraceIdentifier> 
<Description>Get configuration section.</Description> 
<AppDomain>/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/selfiehostie-1-1304834290733034307</AppDomain> 
<ExtendedData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2006/08/ServiceModel/StringTraceRecord"> 
<ConfigurationSection>system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment</ConfigurationSection> 
</ExtendedData> 
</TraceRecord> 
</DataItem> 
</TraceData> 
</ApplicationData> 
</E2ETraceEvent>
```

**Error I am getting**

Getting 500 and The first 1024 bytes of the response, is it possible to get more bytes to see the real error ?

OR

What does above verbose errors means ?

How to find out why WCF service failing ?

Comment: Have you looked at the Event Viewer on the server?  The reason for the 500 error might show up there.

Comment: @Tim yup, There was no error in Event Viewer, even though I fixed the internal issue by guessing the problem and fixing it, but still not sure how to find it without guessing it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried viewing your Trace.svclog file in Microsoft Service Trace Viewer?
It is usually easier to locate error this way, and it shows information in compact form.

If you cannot use that tool - try to look for `<Exception>` tag in trace.

500 server error usually indicates some error on server side, for example that server thrown exception.

EDIT:
You can also try to increase maximum logged message size:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics>
        <messageLogging 
            logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true" 
            logMessagesAtServiceLevel="false" 
            logMalformedMessages="true" 
            logEntireMessage="true" 
            maxSizeOfMessageToLog="100000" 
            maxMessagesToLog="100000" />
    </diagnostics>
```

Comment: I even tried service tool, but there is no exception just 500 error and i know it's error on server which I want to find out, thanks though :-)

Comment: Thank you, I added diagnotics, getting more information but still no error related information